# Is it possible to have multiple google form in single webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-forms

Currently, I am using google form in my landing page but I want to use multiple google forms in the same landing page. Is it possible to do and if yes, please tell me how can it be done?

Comment: Go ahead and do it, then if you have issues please post your code in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and detail what is wrong and what you are having issues with - Also see [**How to ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is to have one form and one submit per page. Two submits per page is just bad UI. The only exception I've seen is having a login form (only username and password) at the top, with a different form at the bottom.

Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_disclosure, which states that making the user decide which form to fill, is bad.

Having two forms in one page, is not that different from having a single form with multiple submit buttons. Its possible, but not a very good idea.

Comment: Could you please tell me, how can I do it. It will be of great help.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Try the program and post specific issues if you have them. @ShivaKarthik